# Requirements for histograms, or why does my histogram only has two bins?

Tags: r, histogram

I am relatively new to statistical studies. I want to plot a histogram of a journal with debit and credit entries. I thought that the 'hist' function would group the entries by itself and would show the level of occurrence.

Unfortunately I only get two bins, even if I have more than two groups of data.[image]

This is the code:

```
options(scipen = 10)
hist(YEAR_POSTEN$BETRAG,probability=TRUE)
lines(density(YEAR_POSTEN$BETRAG),col="red")
```

This is a little overview of the journal, I did it with 'cut' and this was the result that I expected for the histogram:

[image]

This however is a part of my data.frame, that I am actually plotting:

```
YEAR_POSTEN$BETRAG
BETRAG
13409.09
766.3
6702.31
86912.85
8104.66
21603.08
63456.69
38421.7
3398.26
6378.9
15000
10450
6840
6840
-156809.82
114.1
20.93
-20.93
1695.6
1045.02
```

Comment: Could you please post a dataset before `cut`? In the mean time take a look at argument `breaks` of function `hist`.

Comment: You would increase your chances of getting good answer by making your example reproducible. This article on [basics of histogram creation](https://www.r-bloggers.com/basics-of-histograms/) outlines mechanisms behind the creation of bins.

Comment: Histograms don't use magic ">100,000" bins. They are meant to show the full range of a distribution. Your plot is greatly influenced by perhaps a small number of outliers. What you want sounds more like a bar chart than a histogram.

Comment: I don't think there are only two bins.

Comment: I updated my initial post: No there are several other bins, but they are not visible, because most of them have a height of 1. They are not visible. I already used the breaks option, but my two bins will only become narrower, so by adding more breaks, there will be more invisible bins.. I had a little success with ggplot2 by using scale_x_log, but I didn't find out, how to change the label of the x-axis from log to normal numbers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr. Flick is right about the outliers compressing the bulk of the data into one bin near the center.  If the primary interest is in seeing the "shape" of the bulk of the data, the outliers could be excluded prior to running 'hist'.  For instance, at the low end try setting the lower bound as

```
    quantile(YEAR_POSTEN$BETRAG, .025)
```

The .025 (2.5%) can be experimented with.